# Sync ObservableCollection with EF4 Context

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

Pretty straightforward question... What is the most common way for programmers to synchronise the changes in an observable collection with their object context (EF4)? In my situation I have a sql ce 4.0 db using EF4 as my ORM, and I am working with an observable collection that takes objects from the database (MVVM).

Basically I want to know the most logical way to setup some code that adds, removes, modifies the object context when I am manipulating the observable collection.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) event of the ObservableCollection, and add in any EF logic to save inserts/deletions to your database model.

Comment: How would you handle external updates to database in this case?

Comment: That would be a bit more challenging. You would need another mechanism to check for updates, like a dispatch timer, that could throw new records back into your collection. If you wanted this baked into your object, you would indeed need to make your own collection. Your initial question made it sound like you were only updating the ObservableCollection.

Comment: So if we would add an entity to ObservableCollection then CollectionChanged event would make changes to database. So if database rejects the operation (because of constraints or anyother reason) we need to undo the operation on ObservableCollection right?

Comment: There are a couple ways around that, the easiest is using the objects key. New objects from the client wont have a key until after they save, new objects from the database will. You just need a conditional check in your `CollectionChanged` event to ignore objects that already exist (perhaps by updating them instead?).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is to create your own custom collection class that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`. By doing this you have an opportunity to add and delete entities when the collection changes. Updating entities would not be the role of the collection class, but more a function of a model wrapper or viewmodel for each entity.